# User specific folder rights vs group membership rights

Tags: windows, security

If a user individually  granted one set of rights to a folder but a different set of rights is granted to a group to which he belongs, which takes precedence?

I originally thought that the lower rights would take precedence. Now I am thinking that it is the higher set of rights but Deny will take priority over a grant.

How does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my admittedly limited and not rigorously tested experience, a user is granted the union of user and group rights minus the deny parts.

Comment: That is my also admittedly limited and not rigorously tested experience. Thanks!

Comment: This is correct. A permit in any set is enough to allow access, A deny in any set is enough to forbid access.

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder with r-x for user, -w- for group, and --- for other.

I can browse the folder but not modify.

So it looks like user rights override group rights.

Comment: That could also mean that the lower of the two rights are applied. For example, if the group was given read access but the individual write access, what happens?

Comment: Changing folder to -wx for user and r-- for group allows me to create and edit files but I cant list files.  Looks like user rights are still applied.

Comment: Are you talking about Linux?

Comment: whoops!!  Sorry about that!